# Is the following inequality true?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

Suppose that $\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|dx<\epsilon.$ Is the following inequality  true 
$$
\frac{1}{|I|}\int_{I}|f(x)|dx\leq \epsilon
$$
for any subinterval $I\subset [0,1].$

Comment: If $I=[0,1]$ the statement is true with const. 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: take $\varepsilon:=2$, $f(x):=x^{-1/2}$. We have $\int_0^1|f(x)|\mathrm dx=2$ but for any $a\in (0,1)$, $\int_0^a|f(x)|\mathrm dx=2\sqrt a$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. Then
$$\frac{1}{t} \int_0^t f(x) \, dx = \frac{2}{\sqrt{t}},$$
which is not bounded as $t \to 0$, while
$$\int_{0}^1 f(x) \, dx = 2.$$

Comment: @ J.J Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Simplest counter example I could find :
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \begin{cases}1 \qquad x\le \frac12 \\ 0 \qquad x >\frac12\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Then you have $$\int_0^1|f(x)|dx = \frac12 < \epsilon = \frac23$$

Now take $I = [0,\frac12]$, you obtain : $$\frac{1}{|I|}\int_0^{1/2}|f(x)|dx = 1 > \frac23$$